# Autossh fork after entering password

Tags: ssh, password, encryption, autossh

I have an SSH tunnel that I run with autossh to keep it going reliably.

The only issue I have is that I have an encrypted private key which I use to connect.  If I want to fork my process to the background, then I never get the opportunity to enter my password and unlock my key.

Is there any way to have autossh fork *after* I enter my password?

Comment: Facing similar issue, when ssh runs like this: `ssh -f -L 5000:localhost:5000 ovh -N` it asks for password. Same `autossh` command doesn't.

Comment: You could use a key agent to store the decrypted key in memory where SSH can retrieve it. `ssh-agent` would be a common solution.